# How to deploy war to Tomcat from child pom using maven tomcat plugin?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a maven project with the following plugin in the `pom`

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <configuration>
       <path>/casemanager</path>
       <update>true</update>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I do a `mvn tomcat7:run`, my war is deployed just fine. But I have the following configuration in one of the modules of my maven project

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>
                            true
                        </fork>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I want tomcat to run in the `pre-integration-test` phase. Now when I do a `mvn verify`, it starts the server but does not deploy my war. I have even tried providing the `warSourceDirectory`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Seems like when I execute a goal in a child pom, tomcat does not search for wars in other modules on the same level. I had to use `webapp`

```
                        <webapps>
                            <webapp>
                                <groupId>com.fico.fos.casemanager</groupId>
                                <artifactId>casemanager.ui</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                            </webapp>
                        </webapps>
```

I had to use this within the `configuration` tags